# execute_block, initialize_block, apply_extrinsic, finalize_block, offchain_worker exists for struct `Executive` but its trait bound were not satisfied

Tags: parachain, extrinsic, transactions, substrate-parachain-template, offchain-worker

I developed substrate parachain with custom pallets. Actually I wanna add OCW functionality to one of my pallets. After I updated runtime code and added `CreateSignedTransaction` implementation I tried to build my code, but got this errors:

`` the function or associated item `execute_block` exists for struct `Executive<Runtime, Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<..., ..., ..., ...>>, ..., ..., ...>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied ``

And same errors for `initialize_block`, `apply_extrinsic`... Also got this:

`` the trait bound `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, u32>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>: Checkable<ChainContext<Runtime>>` is not satisfied ``

I used default implementation of `UncheckedExtrinsic` like this:

`pub type UncheckedExtrinsic = generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, RuntimeCall, Signature, SignedExtra>;`

What could be a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [`impl Checkable for UncheckedExtrinsic`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame/traits/trait.Checkable.html#impl-Checkable%3CLookup%3E-for-UncheckedExtrinsic%3CLookupSource,+Call,+Signature,+Extra%3E), you can see that this `impl` block is only present if a specific list of `where` clauses are met. The error you are getting is telling you that one of these `where` clauses are not met.

An anecdotal way that I found useful in debugging such issues is this:

- replace the entire implementation block of `fn check(_)` with `todo!()` or similar.
- Now start removing the individual `where` clauses one by one and try re-compiling the code
- The first time when removing a where clause makes your code compile, it means that one was the unmet one.

This should give you a good starting point to then debug further why this clause is not met.

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't have impl of `Checkable` directly in my code, I just use `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic` that already have this impl. Should I do/check  something else?

Comment: @ kianenigma
Hi there! Do you have any ideas considering comment above? 
Thanks!

Comment: This `impl` is coming in from `sp-runtime`, you can use this technique to use a local version of this crate such that you can do your debugging: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#testing-a-bugfix

Comment: Thank you. It's really works. But currently I'm confused a bit, because when I used a local version and try to build - everything worked without any changes. I removed patch and tried to build again - also worked. What it can be? I think it's solved for now, but not clear for me - why?